# Does force upgrade to Windows 11 puts my system under risk?

Tags: security, windows-registry, regedit, windows-11-upgrade

There is a way to upgrade Windows 10 to 11 (even if hardware eligibility check is failed) by editing registry. I.e. to bypass the restriction.
But also I saw some vague information that Microsoft may consider to not push updates to your system in that case.
So is it dangerous? How much?

Comment: Dangerous in what way exactly?  Can you narrow your question into a single concrete concern?

Comment: @Ramhound security updates/vulnerability after upgrade.

Comment: What you have read is over reported. There is absolutely no evidence that your Windows 11 install will NOT receive the same updates. In fact there are numerous questions (more than a dozen) of users complaining that updates on Windows 11 (on unsupported hardware) has caused issues.  Which just indicates those unsupported devices are getting the same updates everyone else is receiving.  There is next to 0% chance Microsoft will block updates on unsupported hardware but it’s still unsupported so don’t expect it to work flawlessly

Comment: If you encounter an issue you can’t live with just reinstall Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound thanks a lot. Though, didn't get 'can't live with just reinstall'.

Comment: If the issues you face on Windows 11 are a deal breaker, and you can’t live with them, just reinstall Windows 10. I am not sure what was unclear about that comment.

Comment: I have W11 installed on 2 non hardware compliant PC's and both get windows updates including defender updates. Both work perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need a system that has UEFI and Secure Boot for starters. Without that, Windows 11 may not even run.

Then you need TPMv2.  I have an older system with TPMv1.2 that runs Windows 11 Insider - not production.

Then the CPU needs to be less than 4 years old.

So the risk on the last point (CPU generation) is fairly small.

The risk on the first 3 is large if you force Windows 11. It may not update properly, or it may not work properly.

I have Windows 11 Insider on a machine not properly set for Windows 11 because it is Insider and Microsoft allowed it. Insider is not the Production version

I have Windows 11 Production on a new Desktop with everything in place for Windows 11 and it installed and updates fine. I replaced a Desktop with no TPM or TPM header to retrofit the chip.

So take care as you may wind up having to reinstall Windows 10.